# Configuring and building mod_wsgi (on macOX 10.12.5 ) to use Apache module inorder to host python web application

Tags: python, xcode, macos, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to use Apache module which can host any Python web application which supports the Python WSGI specification for that i am  configure mod_wsgi in my system (macOX 10.12.5), by following the instructions from https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-on-macosx.html

but after ./configure i am getting  below messages in terminal

> Apples-MacBook-Pro:mod_wsgi-4.5.15 apple$ ./configure checking for
>   apxs2... no checking for apxs... /usr/sbin/apxs apxs:Error:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config
>   not found!. apxs:Error:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config
>   not found!. cat:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/share/apr-1/build-1/libtool:
>   No such file or directory checking for gcc... gcc checking whether the
>   C compiler works... yes checking for C compiler default output file
>   name... a.out checking for suffix of executables...  checking whether
>   we are cross compiling... no checking for suffix of object files... o
>   checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes checking
>   whether gcc accepts -g... yes checking for gcc option to accept ISO
>   C89... none needed checking for prctl... no checking Apache version...
>   apxs:Error:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config
>   not found!. apxs:Error:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config
>   not found!. apxs:Error:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config
>   not found!.
>   2.4.25 checking for python... /usr/local/bin/python apxs:Error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config
>   not found!.
>
> configure: creating ./config.status
>
> config.status: creating Makefile

I had also tried ./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python2.7 --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs but same error

I had already installed the xcode command line tools .Now shows already installed message when i put this command

> xcode-select --install
>
> xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use
>   "Software Update" to install updates

After all this error messages i had tried
                                                                        **pip install mod_wsgi** command and mod_wsgi file exist in the path " /**usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py27.so**" . when i run run the command **"mod_wsgi-express module-config**" i am getting error **mod_wsgi-express: command not found**

Comment: Have you installed the command line compiler tools? Run ``xcode-select``. What happens? You should also use the ``pip`` install method on MacOS X. The method you are using will/may not work due to MacOS X System Integrity Protection. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I had already installed the xcode command line tools .Now shows already installed message Apples-MacBook-Pro:server apple$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates                                                                       And i had used pip install command  mod_wsgi file exist in this pat " /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py27.so"  and when i run run the command "mod_wsgi-express module-config" i am getting error mod_wsgi-express: command not found

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton i had followed https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi this instructions and getting error mod_wsgi-express: command not found

Comment: Which Python distribution are you using, or did you install Python yourself? With that location it isn't the Apple Python distribution or the Python Software Foundation distribution. What do you get for ``which python``?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 12:39:47)  [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]                                     Apple Python distribution  and python version is 2.7

Comment: If you are using Apple Python distro, the installed packages if you hadn't used a virtual environment would have ended up under /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ and not under /usr/local/lib as you point out. Can you try again but this time use a Python virtual environment.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton thanks that get worked